# I have a problem while using the Boyer-Moore algorithm and it gets stuck in a loop until it hits integer limit and breaks

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    public class TraziUzorak
    {
        private string glavniTekst; #main text

        public void UnosGlavnog()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unesite glavni tekst:"); #put the text you want to be searched
            glavniTekst = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public int[] Trazi(string uzorak)
        {
            List<int> pozicije = new List<int>();

            int m = uzorak.Length;
            int n = glavniTekst.Length;

            int[] pomak = PrecomputeShift(uzorak);

            int i = 0;
            while (i <= n - m)
            {
                int j = m - 1;

                while (j >= 0 && uzorak[j] == glavniTekst[i + j])
                    j--;

                if (j < 0)
                {
                    pozicije.Add(i);
                    i += (i + m < n) ? m - pomak[glavniTekst[i + m]] : 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    i += Math.Max(1, j - pomak[glavniTekst[i + j]]);
                }
            }

            return pozicije.ToArray();
        }

        private int[] PrecomputeShift(string uzorak)
        {
            int[] pomak = new int[256];

            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                pomak[i] = uzorak.Length;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < uzorak.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                pomak[uzorak[i]] = uzorak.Length - i - 1;
            }

            return pomak;
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unesite broj ponavljanja traženja:"); #number of times you want to search
            int brojPonavljanja = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            TraziUzorak traziUzorak = new TraziUzorak();

            for (int i = 0; i < brojPonavljanja; i++)
            {
                traziUzorak.UnosGlavnog();

                Console.WriteLine("Unesite uzorak koji želite tražiti:"); #pattern you want to search
                string uzorak = Console.ReadLine();

                int[] rezultati = traziUzorak.Trazi(uzorak);

                if (rezultati.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (int pozicija in rezultati)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(pozicija);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("nema");

                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's for finding a pattern in a word for an example:

```
1 # times you want to search
maatemaatika #the word you want to be searched
aa # pattern you want to find and count how many times it showed up

1
6 #these should be the results to get
```

can someone look at the code I'm really struggling with it before my exam
code is pretty much done with that one fatal flaw

A) the code should return the amount of repeating a pattern in a word when you put the word and the pattern
B) the code breaks on the line 'pozicije.add(i)' and starts counting then breaks because it cant stop and hits the integer limit (when I use breakpoint and check the value it says "-21474882")

Comment: Best way of debugging is write debug info to a file and then look at file.  Without actual input string we probably will not be able to duplicate issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a) what the code should do, b) what the code is not doing, and/or c) what the code is doing instead. If any exceptions are being thrown, provide us with the full text of the exception message. See [ask] for more.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formating of a question. This is my first time using this website so i dont know